# How to prevent Plotly from parsing HTML in labels?

Tags: javascript, python, plotly

By default Plotly parses HTML tags in labels and titles to format them.

Is there any way to disable this? I want to have raw text "as is".

For example I want this text:

```
This is my <b>sample</b> text.
```

To be rendered as above and not like this:

This is my **sample** text.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, the only trick that I have found is to substitute '<' and '>' with a Unicode character that look very much like them, but are not - which obviously prevents Plotly from parsing them as HTML. But this is more of a hack than a solution...